# Pause Scrapy after a number of requests or scraped items

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I tried to add `item_count = 0` in my init function then `self.item_count += 1` before each yield item.

After that I've added `if self.item_count == x time.sleep(y)`.

But this doesn't seem to work.

I want to add this because the site that I'm trying to scrape has an anti scraping policy and I cannot pass 150k items.
So I think that making a pause of 5-10 minutes each 50k items would help me to over come this issue.

Comment: You said that you added `if item_count == x: time.sleep(y)` , is this correct or it suppose to be:`if self.item_count == x time.sleep(y)`?

Comment: It was self.item_count I misspelled here. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Then it should work. Can you post a snippet of this function's code?

Comment: `yield product`
`if self.product_count == 50000 :`
`time.sleep(300)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `from_crawler` class method to connect the `item_scraped` signal to a spider method. Then in the spider method, check if the `item_count` is divisible by 50000 and then pause the engine for the required time using `crawler.engine.pause()` method. Resume the crawl afterwards using the `crawler.engine.unpause()` method.

In below sample code, I have implemented a 10 seconds pause every 5 items as an example. Modify it to suit your needs (i.e. say 5 minutes every 50000 items).

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
import time

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
    item_count = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(SampleSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
        spider.crawler = crawler
        return spider

    def item_scraped(self, item):
        # increase item count and then check if the item count is 5 from the previous pause
        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count % 5 == 0:
            self.logger.info(f"Pausing scrape job...item count = {self.item_count}")
            self.crawler.engine.pause()
            time.sleep(10)
            self.crawler.engine.unpause()
            self.logger.info(f"Resuming crawl...")

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, I've tried everything. The only thing that worked was waiting more than 2 minutes each page. Since we have 50 pages and 1500 items I think for this case we should use other tool.

Comment: Remember that answers are best if they can help many people in the future, not just one. So post comments that aren't really answers as comments, not as answers. –